# I want eject any user action until a function is done, iphone app!

Tags: iphone

i'm writing an iphone app integrate with webservice.When user wait to login on web,I want eject any user action until login is done. Please help me! thanks!

Comment: Do you want to *reject* any user action, that is, to prevent them from doing anything until the login is done?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to archive.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to pop up a modal view controller using `presentModalViewController`.  Another way would be to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't multithread your code the user shouldn't be able to interact with your UI while you're getting and sending data.

Alternatively you could present a semitransparent loading screen over the whole UI -while loading- that intercepts every touch event.

Comment: I have use multithread ( waitUntilDone:YES ), but when user press continuous on login button, my app will be crash. Plese give a solution for it!

Comment: @dongmh - if that's your problem, just disable the login button (set enabled = NO) when they first click it, then enable it again when the process is done.